# reset index in dense_rank or row_number after variable partitioning over changes

Tags: sql, db2, dense-rank

I'm using DB2 SQL. I have the following:

`select * from mytable order by Var,Varseq`

```
ID    Var    Varseq
--    ---    ------
1     A      1
1     A      2
1     B      1
1     A      3
2     A      1
2     C      1
```

but  would like to get:

```
ID    Var    Varseq    NewSeq
--    ---    ------    ------
1     A      1         1
1     A      2         2
1     B      1         1
1     A      3         1
2     A      1         1
2     C      1         1
```

However `dense_rank` produces the same as the original result. I hope you can see the difference in the desired output - in the 4th line when ID=1 returns to Var=A, I want the index reset to 1, instead of carrying on as 3. i.e. I would like the index to be reset every time Var changes for a given ID.

for ref here was my query:

```
SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, VAR ORDER BY VARSEQ) FROM MYTABLE
```

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your question does not make sense unless you have a column that specifies the ordering of the rows.

Comment: You must explain conditions when the index must be reset. Rows in a table are not ordered by default. So, you can't say, that NewSeq for 4-th must be reset because it's sorted before the 3-rd one. You must explain why it's sorted so, if it's the case.

Comment: have edited question to reflect how/why the index should be reset. i.e. when Var changes for a given ID.

Comment: Saying just "Var changes" is not enough. The order may be `(A, 1), (A, 2), (B, 1)` or `(A, 1), (B, 1), (A, 2)`: You must provide `order by` clause to specify the exact order inside a given ID.

Comment: edited to include order by Var,Varseq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of a gaps-and-islands problem.  However, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Without a column that specifies the overall ordering, your question does not make sense.

In this case, the difference of row numbers will do what you want.  But you need an overall ordering column:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by id, var, seqnum - seqnum2 order by <ordering col>) as newseq
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by <ordering col>) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by id, var order by <ordering col>) as seqnum2
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: fantastic - and nice to know the name of the problem, I get this type of problem quite a bit!

Comment: @brucezepplin . . . I spend half of yesterday solving a particularly complicated form of this problem.  The answers are not always quite so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer yet, but just to have better formatting.

```
WITH TAB (ID, Var, Varseq) AS 
(
VALUES
  (1, 'A', 1)
, (1, 'A', 2)
, (1, 'A', 3)
, (1, 'B', 1)
, (2, 'A', 1)
, (2, 'C', 1)
)
SELECT *
FROM TAB
ORDER BY ID, <order keys>;
```

You specified `Var, Varseq` as `<order keys>` in the query above.
The result is:

```
|ID         |VAR|VARSEQ     |
|-----------|---|-----------|
|1          |A  |1          |
|1          |A  |2          |
|1          |A  |3          |
|1          |B  |1          |
|2          |A  |1          |
|2          |C  |1          |
```

But you need the following according to your question:

```
|ID         |VAR|VARSEQ     |
|-----------|---|-----------|
|1          |A  |1          |
|1          |A  |2          |
|1          |B  |1          |
|1          |A  |3          |
|2          |A  |1          |
|2          |C  |1          |
```

So, please, edit your question to specify such a `<order keys>` clause to get the result you need. And please, run your query getting such an order on your system first before posting here...